# React native scroll image continously creating marquee effect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I am new in react native , I want to scroll the image continuously bottom to top in react native.

We can scroll image in html using marquee tag.

E.g.,

```
 <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up">
   <img src="../t1.png"/>
 </marquee>
```

Similar thing I want to achieve in react native.

currently I am using the below code

```
<Animatable.Image 
  animation={{
    from: { translateY: 0 },
    to: { translateY: -70 },
  }}
  duration={10000}
  delay={1}
  easing={t => Math.pow(t, 1.7)}
  iterationCount={100}
  useNativeDriver
  source={require('./../assets/images/gradient_bg.png')} 
  style={LoginStyles.scrollerImage}>
 </Animatable.Image>
```

this code works but it resets the the posion of image to 0 and starts again can someone help me fix this
Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable#looping may be you should remove `interationCount={100}`?

Comment: If I remove interationCount={100} it loop only once and then stops, I want it to loop as a marquee

Answer (score 1):

> Set the iteration count to infinite

`iterationCount="infinite"`

If you read their [documentation](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable#looping) , there's an option to make the iteration in an infinite loop.

Comment: I tried that also, it resets the image to 0 position and then starts the animation doesn't behave like an marquee.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this package
[react-native-marquee-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-marquee-scroll)

It works for me.